# $f:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous.Defined as $g\left( x\right) =\int _{0}^{x}f\left( t\right) dt$

Tags: analysis

$f:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous.Defined as $g\left( x\right) =\int _{0}^{x}f\left( t\right) dt$.Then how can I show that $g:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniform continuous?

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\|f\|_\infty = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \in \mathbb{R}$, by Weierstrass' theorem. Then, for any $x<y$,
$$
\left| g(x) - g(y) \right| \leq \int_x^y |f(t)| \, dt \leq \|f\|_\infty |x-y|.
$$